# Est-ce que toutes les phrases sont correctes?

Tags: participe-présent

A) Pensant qu’il était midi, j’ai mangé une soupe.

B) J’ai mangé une soupe en pensant qu’il était midi.

C) J’ai mangé une soupe, pensant qu’il était midi.

Si oui, quelle est la nuance entre  la phrase dans laquelle la particule « en » est employée et celles dans lesquelles elle ne l’est pas.

Au sens de « Comme je pensais qu’il était midi (alors qu’en réalité il était 9h), j’ai mangé une soupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les phrases A) et C) sont équivalentes. La proposition subordonnée circonstancielle de cause sous-entend qu'il n'était pas midi. Le sens de penser est ici: [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pensant/1) **B.− 1. a) β)** *Synonyme de croire, supposer (que) ou de avoir le sentiment, l'impression (que).* ou **B.− 2. b)** : *Avoir le sentiment, l'impression*. Ce sont bien les formes attendues puisqu'il n'était en réalité que 9 heures.

La phrase B) n'indique qu'une simultanéité des faits où la relation de cause à effet n'est pas marquée. Il n'est pas complètement exclu que ce se soit effectivement passé à midi. On aurait pu écrire *J'ai mangé une soupe en écoutant la radio* ou *J'ai pensé qu'il était midi (j'ai songé au fait qu'il était midi) en mangeant une soupe*. La phrase n'est pas incorrecte mais rend de manière moins franche l'idée attendue.

Answer (score 0):

Toutes ont une syntaxe correcte.  Les participes présents et le gérondif expriment tous la cause.

> (**LBU**) **Rem** On dit souvent, par ex., que le gérondif marque ici le temps, là la cause, ailleurs encore l'opposition ou la condition, tout cela sans changer de forme. Cela prouve que le gérondif ne suffit pas à indiquer ces différentes valeurs et donc qu'il n'en indique en soi aucune. C'est le contexte, la situation qui font établir entre les faits une relation logique qui n'est pas exprimée grammaticalement.

La cause est aussi bien exprimée avec ou sans « en » ; il ne semble pas y avoir de nuance.

Il y a une différence d'usage ; alors que « B) » se dit couramment  dans la langue parlée, « C) » n'est pas très utilisé.